# java inter object communication

Tags: java, swing, oop, design-patterns

Still learning Java.

Again Swing has caused me to ask this but it is really a general OO question.  If I have a master class (that contains main()) it creates a new object "A" that does something, the master class now has a reference to that object, how does object "B" get access to the attributes of that object?

The only way I can think of is for the master class to create a new object "B", passing object "A" as a parameter to the constructor, which I suppose is O.K. but doesn't this make event handling potentially difficult.

For example, and perhaps this is a poor design which is causing the problem. I have a master class with the programme logic, that creates a standard Swing frame, with a menu, the menu items having action listeners. But the actionlistener needs to interact with external objects.

So some code (ignoring the details) :

The main class, containing the programme logic and the save and load methods, etc :

```java
public final class TheProgramme implements WindowListener }
    private static final TheProgramme TP = new TheProgramme();
    // Declare Class variables, instance variables etc.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShewGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShewGUI() {
        TP.populateAndShew();
    }

    private void populateAndShew() {
        final StandardFrame sF = new StandardFrame("TheProgramme");
        theFrame = sF.getMainFrame();
        theFrame.addWindowListener(this);
        theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        theFrame.pack(); theFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
...
}
```

So we have created a standard frame object which has created a menu, empty panel and status bar, but with event listeners on the menu items :

```java
public class StandardFrame {
    // Declare instance variables that must be visible to the ActionListener inner class

    public StandardFrame(String theTitle) {
        mainFrame = new JFrame(theTitle);
        mainFrame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar()); // ... the menu bar and ...
        mainFrame.setContentPane(createBlankPanel()); // ... a blank panel
        java.net.URL imageURL = TheProgramme.class.getResource("images/icon.png");
        if (imageURL != null) {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
            mainFrame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        }
    }

    public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        ActionListener menuEvents = new MenuListener();
        JMenuBar aMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File"); fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        ...
        aMenuBar.add(fileMenu);
        ...
        JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New", KeyEvent.VK_N); newItem.addActionListener(menuEvents);
        newItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        ...
        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        ...
        return aMenuBar;
    }
}

class MenuListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String actionCommand = ae.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case "New":
                // !!! here we need to call a method in an object to create a new document object !!!
                break;
             case "Reformat":
                // !!! here we need to call a method in the object created above
         }
     }
}
```

The first problem is the actionlistener on the menu items calls a method to create an object but it is not a call to a static method.
The second problem is it needs to be be able to call a method in that new object later on as a result of another menu choice.

Comment: some sample code would help.

Comment: More details about the problems are needed to give an answer. At the moment it's a little difficult to understand what the problem is. Generally objects start out with not knowing any other objects; you can pass details in constructors or set them later with a setXxx() method. Try to draw a diagram of the different objects and use that to decide which object needs to know which other object. Generally you should separate UI from data classes though, so if you have an model object pointing to a UI object you've got it the wrong way round.

Comment: What you seem to be wanting is some kind of [MVC](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) structure. You're right to be worried by your current structure, but probably for the wrong reasons. At some point, you need to pass a refernce of something to some one in order to be notified when things need to change, see the [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) for more details. You should also investigate the concept of "programming to interface and not implementation" which is also related

Comment: Try to come up with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Where is the method that creates a document is defined, in which class? Also, which class maintains a reference to a (selected) document that needs to be reformatted? Is it all part of `StandardFrame`? If `MenuListener` is an inner class it has access to everything in `StandardFrame`.

Comment: @Aqua I have tried to keep the StandardFrame class simply to make the blank programme screen and listen for menu events, the new document object is a different class.  One of the problems is how do I get the new object reference back to StandardFrame so that a method can be called from there, at the moment the main programme is called from the action listener and it creates the new document, but it is a call to a static method.

Comment: @TimtheEnchanter: See my answer below.  It uses no static methods and can handle multiple documents, at the same time if needed.

Comment: @TimtheEnchanter you can define appropriate methods in `StandardFrame` (or other class) that can accept a newly created document, ie - `public void setDocument(Document d)` and `public Document getDocument()`. Then, call these methods from `MenuListener`.

Comment: @Aqua Because these calls are from the MenuListener would they not have to be static?

Comment: @TimtheEnchanter no, see [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for some definitions and examples. If `MenuListener` is an inner class it call non static methods in `StandardFrame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic way to do this in [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is to bind the objects together at runtime.  The controller, your action listener, takes parameters to indicate which view and model it is to act on.

This use of parameters is also called "Dependency Injection," as Aqua mentions.

```
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Model model = new Model();
      View view = new View();
      ActionListener listener = new MyActionListener( model, view );
      view.addActionListener( listener );
   }

   private static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener
   {
      private Model model;
      private View view;

      public MyActionListener( Model model, View view )
      {
         this.model = model;
         this.view = view;
      }
   }
```

In Java you can cheat a little since the ActionEvent has a pointer to the source of the event (normally the view/JComponent that generated the event.

```
private static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener
{
  private Model model;

  public MyActionListener( Model model )
  {
     this.model = model;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
  {
     JComponent source = (JComponent) e.getSource();
     // source == "view"...
  }
}
```

To set a new document, you can create a "document holder" class.  The "new" menu item puts a new document in the holder class.  All other menu items "get" the document from the holder class.  This is a fairly strict OO paradigm which uses no static methods or fields, although it is a little tedious.

Set up:

```
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      ModelDocumentHolder model = new ModelDocumentHolder();
      View view = new View();
      ActionListener listener = new NewDocument( model );
      view.addActionListener( listener );
      View view2 = new View();
      view2.addActionListener( new RegularListener( model ) );
   }
```

New document listener:

```
   private static class NewDocument implements ActionListener
   {
      private ModelDocumentHolder model;

      public NewDocument( ModelDocumentHolder model )
      {
         this.model = model;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
      {
         model.setDoc( new Document() );
      }
   }
```

Most other menu items:

```
   private static class RegularListener implements ActionListener
   {
      private ModelDocumentHolder model;

      public RegularListener( ModelDocumentHolder model )
      {
         this.model = model;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
      {
         JComponent source = (JComponent) e.getSource();
         Document doc = model.getDoc();
         // do stuff...
      }
   }
```

The holder class:

```
   private static class ModelDocumentHolder
   {
      private Document doc;

      public Document getDoc()
      {
         return doc;
      }

      public void setDoc( Document doc )
      {
         this.doc = doc;
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, (and it's really hard to know if this is an answer to your question, as it's quite vague) this is what `setModel(...)` and `addListener(...)` are for.

The "constructor coordinator" aka "master class", creates the models (the swing Model classes).  It creates the views (JWidgets) and it sets the models of the views.  In Swing it is easy to rely upon the default constructed model (populated with the JWidget default constructor), but maybe in your case, you should find the one widget causing problems and rewrite it make the model setting explicit.

If you have extended a Jwhatever, then keep in mind that setModel(...) typically does something like

```
if (this.model != null) {
   this.model.removeListener(this);
}
// clear the cached last "view" of the model
clearCachedData(...);
if (model != null) {
   this.model = model;
   // restore the "view" of the new model.
   grabCachedData(...);
   this.model.addListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope my interpretation of the question is correct. You can inject/provide whatever object you need to the action implementation. Here is an example that uses an interface for better abstraction as a callback from `actionPerformed`. When action completes it call its callback to notify whoever is interested. In this case, the panel is notified and updates its text area with some text.

The interface:

```
public interface ActionCallback {
    public void documentCreated(String name);
}
```

Here is the UI:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestAction extends JPanel implements ActionCallback {
    private JTextArea area;
    public TestAction() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        area = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(area));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void documentCreated(String name) {
        area.append(String.format("Created %s\n", name));
    }

    public static class NewAction extends AbstractAction {
        private ActionCallback callback;
        private Component parent;

        public NewAction(ActionCallback callback, Component parent){
            super("New");
            this.callback = callback;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent, "Name", "new name");
            if (value != null){
                callback.documentCreated(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
            public void run() {   
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                TestAction panel = new TestAction();
                frame.add(panel);

                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
                menuBar.add(menu);

                JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new NewAction(panel, frame));
                menu.add(item);
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a reference of yourself (A) to an other object (B) tends to happen quite frequently in GUI code. You could use an context object, which you pass to all classes and which contains references to relevant references and might hold some global information. In simple cases, "main program class" is used as context and passed around.

Depending on what classes you use, this might also be useful: [Component#getParent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29).