# Access class instance that is initialised in action event java

Tags: java, swing, class, instances

I am trying to have one class read a variable belonging to one instance of another class. The class that is being read from is only initiated once a JButton is pressed. From my experimenting it seems that I am unable to access any of the class's variables (maybe because the compiler isn't certain the first class will actually be initiated?)

Does anyone know of a way around this?

sorry about the vagueness.

```
public class MainClass extends JComponent implements ActionListener{
   JButton button = new JButton("Run Program");
   MainClass INSTANCE = new MainClass()  // create an instance of the main class to refer to later
        constructor(){

        this.add(button);
        button.addActionEventListener(this);
        }

    actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource == button){
     NextClass nextClass = new NextClass();  // class being read from
     FinalClass finalClass = new FinalClass(); // class doing the reading
    }



   public class NextClass{
   boolean state = true; // what is being read

    constructor(){}
   }



    public class FinalClass{
    constructor(){
    if(MainClass.INSTANCE.nextClass.state == true){do something...}
    }
    }
```

Basically, the nextClass and finalClass instances get created when the button is pressed. inside the Final class I want to check the state variable in the nextClass instance of the NextClass Class. I dont seem to be able to gain accesses to the state variable or any other variable or function in the next class. My assumption being because there isnt a guarantee that the nextClass will actually be initiated?

Comment: Can you clarify little bit more

Comment: A complete (if minimal) code example showing your problem might help clarify things. As it is, this question is too vague for me to understand. Please edit your question rather than trying to post a code example in comments.

Comment: put your code in the post

Comment: the code is very long. I gave a concise scenario of what I'm trying to do

Comment: `"sorry about the vagueness"` -- rather than apologize, clarify.

Comment: a) I did clarify directly under the apololgy
b) @markspace the link you posted goes to this question. I have no other question like this...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  Try [this question instead, it is similar to yours.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099124/java-inter-object-communication/25099568)

Comment: I think that you may be presenting us an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), which is why I asked for further clarification. Often it is better for you to tell us more of your overall goal, the larger problem that you're trying to solve rather than your planned code solution for it, because often there is a better approach to be found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I think I figured out how to do it. I couldnt initialise nextClass in mainClass because then it would start running pre-emptively, and simply declaring it wasn't doing the trick either.

The solution was creating a new constructor for next class that accepts a parameter. the constructor would however be empty (no methods to call or anything). This way I could initialise nextClass without causing it to run its methods pre-emptively.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainClass INSTANCE` object doesn't have a `nextClass` field. The only `nextClass` name exists as a local variable in the `actionPerformed` method. To do what you want, I think you simply need to eliminate the local variable and make `nextClass` a field of `MainClass`. (It's a little hard to tell because the code you posted is more pseudocode than actual Java.)