# How can I communicate between multiple classes?

Tags: java, oop, instantiation

I have three classes. For example's sake, I'll call them AwesomeClass, CoolClass, PrettyClass. AwesomeClass instantiates an object of CoolClass and PrettyClass. Now, I want CoolClass to change a variable inside PrettyClass.

What is the best way to go about this? One way that I can think of would be to send the reference of PrettyClass to CoolClass, and then CoolClass could do something like `instanceOfPrettyClass.setSomeVariable("42");`. Or I could treat AwesomeClass as a controller and the other two classes as views (which is what they're being used as) and have CoolClass call some method in AwesomeClass which then calls another method in PrettyClass, but that feels very messy.

EDIT some example code

```
public class AwesomeClass
{
    public AwesomeClass()
    {
        CoolClass coolClass = new CoolClass();
        PrettyClass prettyClass = new PrettyClass();
    }
}

public class CoolClass
{
    public CoolClass()
    {
        Color colour = Color.RED;
    }
}

public class PrettyClass
{
    public PrettyClass()
    {
        //I want to set coolClass's colour to Color.BLACK here
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code what youve done so far

Comment: You, probably, need getters and setters.

Comment: If both `CalledClassA` and `CalledClassB` are views - how come `CalledClassA` needs to change something in `CalledClassB` ?

Comment: Added some code. 

@alfasin my actual code has a toolbox panel in one class and a drawing panel in another class. I want selection of a particular tool via radio button in the toolbox panel to affect what shape is then drawn on the drawing panel.

Comment: Sounds like the drawing panel should be registered to the radio-selection event on the toolbox.

Comment: accessing one class from another is possible by two ways, By creating an object of the class inside the second class or by making the variable to be static. I don't clearly understand your question, hope my comment helps.

Comment: @alfasin what do you mean by registered?

Comment: @Birdie I mean: to submit a callback that will be triggered once the event occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has answered this.  I think you have the right idea, although it might be backwards.

```
public class AwesomeClass
{
    public AwesomeClass()
    {
        CoolClass coolClass = new CoolClass();
        PrettyClass prettyClass = new PrettyClass( coolClass );  // change
    }
}

public class CoolClass()
{
    private Color colour;  // change

    public CoolClass
    {
        colour = Color.RED;  // change
    }

    public void setColor( Color color ) {  // add setter
      colour = color;
    }
}

public class PrettyClass
{

    public PrettyClass( CoolClass cc )  // change
    {
        //I want to set coolClass's colour to Color.BLACK here
        cc.setColor( Color.BLACK );  // change
    }
}
```

I think that's it.

Comment: Is that the "best" way to do it? That's what I was planning on doing but wasn't sure if it was best-practice, as I'm pretty new to OOP. If it is, thanks very much!

Comment: I see above that you mention GUI objects.  Look up [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and check out [another answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099124/java-inter-object-communication/25099568#25099568).  But basically yes it is best.  I think though you should re-ask your question with the actual GUI objects you want to use.  You'll get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using constructors:

```
public class CalledClassA {
        public void doCalledClassA() {..} 
}

public class CalledClassB {
   private CalledClassA calledClassA;
   public CalledClassB(CalledClassA calledClassA) {
      this.calledClassA = calledClassA;
   }

   public void doSomething() {
      calledClassA.doCalledClassA();
   }
}
```

or using setters as suggested above.
I prefer using contractors as possible from the following reasons: [REPEAT AFTER ME: SETTER INJECTION IS A SYMPTOM OF DESIGN PROBLEMS](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2012/06/05/repeat-after-me-setter-injection-is-a-symptom-of-design-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

Can we claim a static method "set" in CoolClass ? We don't need to pass a reference as parameter in "PrettyClass" constructor in that case. Any time we want to change the color, just use CoolClass.set(...) to do it.

Comment: This is not answer of this question. you can write this in comments section.